# Как написать более правильно PHP

Tags: php, оптимизация

```
$tmp = 0;
foreach($result['response']['items'] as $post ) {
    if ($post['date'] <= $only_old_post_time ) {
        $tmp++;
    }
}
if (!$tmp){
    $offset += 100;
}
```

как написать данный участок кода более элегантно, правильно, чтоб работало быстрее, и мб можно сделать как то стандартными функциями?

Comment: можно `$tmp = count(array_filter(...`

Answer (score 1):

У вас вполне рабочий вариант: перебрать массив так и так придется. Можно как @splash58 написал (хотя там создается лишний массив), или через [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$tmp = array_reduce( $result['response']['items'], "is_old", 0);

function is_old( $count, $post) {
    return $post['date'] <= $only_old_post_time ? ++$count : $count;
}
```